# Where can I find good test image(s) to send to a print lab?

Tags: color-management, printing, tests

I am looking for a good test image to send to a print lab, to [test my system's color calibration](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6708/how-can-i-validate-my-monitors-color-calibration).

I'll be sending my own photos too, of course, but I would also like to include one or two test images to exercise the process (and my knowledge of color and color problems) more thoroughly than my own photos might.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the one we suggest using at SmugMug, the full sized image is available for anybody to use.

http://cmac.smugmug.com/SmugMug/Test-prints/Calibration-prints/122238_UAxBs#5637776_3P7qj-A-LB

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shizam! That one looks very nice. Is there a blurb anywhere on the SmugMug website that I can point printers to if they complain about permissions?

Comment: I asked around and its fine to have this printed, I'll see about updating the caption on that page to indicate this.

Comment: Yea, one of the nice 'features' of that image is it has 4 types of skin tones in it which is a boon for people-pictures :)

Comment: I have used this image very successfully. I would also recommend that you look at SmugMug for the printing itself as they do a great job helping with the color management issues. They have two labs to pick from. I have saved lots of money and frustration through their help.