# Where may I find this camera test image?

Tags: printing, testing, tests

So I wanted to compare the cameras of two phones that look like good contenders to be purchased as the daily driver.. I went over to [GSMArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/piccmp.php3?idType=1) and found an interesting test for these cameras-
[image]

I found it again over at [Imaging resource.com](https://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/canon-eos-m50/FULLRES/EOSM50hRES_ACRu300r03.HTM)

This makes me think that this is probably a standard test.

So, I wanted to know where I could get this image(the true image) from and what should I consider while printing it..

*(P.S. for those of you wondering, I want to test these cameras in the showrooms myself to be sure of the settings required to achieve the best image and the work to be done to achieve that.)*

*(P.P.S Saw [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7509/where-can-i-find-good-test-images-to-send-to-a-print-lab) and this too looks like a gd picture to test colour)*

Comment: IMHO for this kind of test you could just as well shoot at any printed text. Lighting conditions may also have a big influence on image quality.

Comment: Well, yeah..I first thought the same.. But, frankly I was very impressed by this test and the marvellous way it could literally test most facets of a camera(except color i.e.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interesting question.

Please google "ISO test charts", or "test charts targets" To my knowledge that one is ISO-12233 "Digital Resolution Still Camera Test Chart".

It is a bit expensive though, so you can find some other camera test chart options on Amazon, or perhaps find some second-hand on eBay.

But as you want to use them in a showroom... You probably need a standardized test.

---

Some explanations here.

**If your workflow needs to be standardized, use some tools for the standardization**. If you only want some target to compare, I guess you will be fine with some generic products.

I am not sure if you could commercially use the patterns of the test chart, but if you understand the idea behind them you can prepare some of your own. (Or use the [link](https://www.graphics.cornell.edu/%7Ewestin/misc/res-chart.html) xenoid posted)

**I. For a resolution-only chart, aka Black and white**

What needs to be taken into account is the resolution of the file and the resolution of the output, besides the interpolation method used on them.

A real test chart is printed on high-resolution photographic systems, which gives crisp lines, up to 2400-3200 DPI. Probably you can ask if a prepress bureau can either print directly on photographic paper, or print a negative on film and then make a transfer. This is not expensive, but you need to find someone that can print it.

The files must be, either in vector format or at the exact same resolution of the printer, 2400 or 3200 DPI at 1 bit. You should not use a normal 24-bit or grayscale image.

---

If the image is not photographically printed the image will degrade, depending on the output system.

If the print is lithography and printed as line art, starting with the vector file or the 1 bit image, I am guessing it will lose around half the original resolution on the thin lines due to dot gain. The lines will be a bit wider so the white spaces are a bit narrower. But if it is well printed I think they will work well enough to do some comparation tests.

---

If the images are printed on a laser-toner or ink-jet printer, I would not risk using a 1-bit raster image, and only use a vector file.

You will have dots of tonner around the line which will give you a slight smudgy edge. Try to find a black-only laser printer at the highest resolution you can find. 600 DPI is normal, try to find a 1200DPI one.

If you find an inkjet one, you probably will have an additional loss of sharpness if the printer is using CMY inks besides the black.

"You can increase" the resolution of your chart... doubling the size. A 600DPI target will look like a 1200DPI at double the distance, but of course, distance is another variable on a lens test.

**II. For color targets**

No. Do not print your own. Find a Color target of a recognized brand. Datacolor has some economic models.

They are printed with direct paint, matt finish. Any color print will have a deviation on the color. Color is FAR more important than lens resolution if you want to do some commercial work.

---

Some "random" links.

ISO page: https://www.iso.org/standard/71696.html

I have not use this site: https://www.appliedimage.com/product-category/test-targets-and-charts/iso-test-charts/iso-12233-digital-resolution-still-camera-test-chart-qa-72/

It seems that this is a legacy model: https://www.imatest.com/solutions/iso-12233/

A cheap option: [https://www.amazon.com/DGK-Color-Tools-Resolution-Professional/dp/B00F1YEEHA/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=camera+test+target&qid=1634229618&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00F1YEEHA) but the reviews say that they are "screened" so, the lines are not sharp.

A good finding from xenoid, a vector file of a similar chart: https://www.graphics.cornell.edu/%7Ewestin/misc/res-chart.html

Comment: OTOH the OP want to shoot things in show rooms, so we aren't exactly aiming for accuracy...

Comment: This is one of the best explanations I have seen for this purpose...I will be using your techniques to print the test from my laser printer....As for color,  well I could always improvise with something ..Thanks a ton to both @xenoid and Rafael once again

Comment: Your penultimate link (to amazon) appears to just link to a search page, not to a specific product.

Comment: For colour, X-rite (Calibrite) is recommended over Datacolor, with some rumours that Datacolor is actually inaccurate.

Comment: I could not tell. X-rite is more recognizable as a brand for sure, but a "rumor" could also be misleading. It would be interesting to see the data.

Answer (score 8):

See [here](https://www.graphics.cornell.edu/%7Ewestin/misc/res-chart.html). Of course it has to be printed correctly to be of any value.

Answer (score 1):

The camera review site DPReview uses a similar resolution test chart and has an [old blog post](https://www.dpreview.com/articles/3692631027/newreschart) about it.  Someone in the comments then linked to [this German site](https://www.big-photo.de/b.i.g.-res7-testtafel-fuer-kameras-und-objektive) that sells a similar chart (maybe the same chart?).  The [Test and Reference](https://www.big-photo.de/licht-studio/testtafeln-referenzkarten/) section of their site also has color charts and a few other things.  I don't speak German, so I was just looking at the pretty pictures.

I know this isn't a great answer, but its a real world example of how I found such a thing if nothing else.

Comment: Thanks a ton @JPhi1618 for answering... I see in this answer the genuine thrill of research which made you go even to a German site ;)).. Much appreciated research on your part